# Can I solder two USB cables together?

Tags: usb, soldering

I've got two USB computer mice, one with a defect click button and one with a defect USB plug. Would there any issue if I simply cut them open and soldered together the mouse part of one with the USB plug from the other? Or the USB plug from any old USB cable, for that matter.

They're both USB-A and not USB3. I know that there's a length limit for USB to get timing to work. Would a so-so solder job affect that? Could there be any other electronics in the plug part that differs between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soldering in a replacement usb cable is easy enough, just make sure that the correct wires go on the correct terminals.

**Most** usb cables have red and black as supply positive and negative, while the data pair are green and white. If different you need to check which is which with a multimeter or continuity tester.

Just to show one, this is from an old cable I was testing something else with:
[image]

Note that the "red" is more pink...

Comment: _Most_ is the keyword. I've seen USB leads with the red/black/green/white wires but not following the expected code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replace the USB cable from one mouse to another. Replace the whole cable so you don't have to splice up the wires.

Comment: The cable is "built-in", not detachable, in both mice, so I think I can't avoid splicing up the wires.

Comment: You open the mouse, replace the cable, and close the mouse?

Comment: Sounds trickier than splicing the cable! I'll give it a try

Comment: IIRC some mice use an internal connector where the cable connects to the PCB, so I think it's definitely worth taking a look inside since it might be as easy as unplugging one cable and plugging it into the other.

Comment: If you don't want to open the mouse, consider buying a solder connector shell and some heath shrink tubing and just putting a new end on.  Mouse cables are high-flex, it's going to be hard to do a splice that comes out nice and durable.